# Set individual bins of FFT chain in SuperCollider

Tags: sound-synthesis, supercollider

I am working on image-to-sound project and trying to implement additive syntheses in **SuperCollider**. I want to use inverse DFFT to sum over (hundreds of) sine waves instead of creating a `SinOsc` synth for each of them.

All SuperCollider documentation says that `IFFT` consumes something called "FFT chain" produced by `FFT` (and transformed by `PV_*` functions):

```
Time-domain signal -> FFT -> [PV_* -> PV_* -> ...] -> IFFT
```

But for my application I don't need *FFT stage* since I already know how my signal is represented in frequency domain. What I want instead is:

```
Frequency-domain signal -> Manually constructed FFT chain -> IFFT
```

The "frequency-domain signal" is a sequence of numpy arrays representing a signal in frequency domain which I already have in my Python application. So, I need to pass this information to SuperCollider.

From what I understand *FFT chain* means some kind of data stream but I don't understand how to manually write data into it.

I've also tried to play with silent FFT chain (e.g. get `FTT` of `Silence.ar`) but I have no clue how to manually set individual frequency bins either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few options.

1. use the [PackFFT](http://doc.sccode.org/Classes/PackFFT.html) Ugen. This lets you use an arbitrary array of UGens for magnitude and phase. Here's an example, hopefully clearer for your purpose than the one in the helpfile:

   ```
   s = Server.local;
   s.waitForBoot {

   Routine {    
       n = 512;

       // massively multichannel control busses
       ~magBus = Bus.control(s, n);
       ~phaseBus = Bus.control(s, n);

       s.sync;

       ~synth = { var mags, phases, chain, snd;
           mags = n.collect ({ |i| In.kr(~magBus.index + i) });
           phases = n.collect ({ |i| In.kr(~phaseBus.index + i) });
           chain = FFT(LocalBuf(n*2), Silent.ar);
           chain = PackFFT(chain, n, [mags, phases].flop.flatten);
           Out.ar(0, IFFT(chain).dup);
       }.play(s);

       s.sync;

       // raise each bin magnitude in a random order.
       // eventually results in wide-band noise, so watch your ears...
       Array.series(n).scramble.do({ arg i;
           i.postln;
           ~magBus.setAt(i, -16.dbamp.rand);
           (0.01 + 0.2.rand).wait;
       });    
   }.play;    
   };
   ```

   Note that the size of the FFT buffer here is twice the number of frequency bands. I believe this is correct but not 100% sure.
2. use the `.pvcollect` and `.pvcalc` methods of [PV_ChainUGen](http://doc.sccode.org/Classes/PV_ChainUGen.html). (See the helpfile for example code.) In theory, you can use an Array ref as a SynthDef argument and use that to arbitrarily set magnitudes and phases of a running synth on the fly. In practice I've found this to be a fragile approach: SC is picky about FFT block sizes (they are limited by audio device block size); very large SynthDefs are problematic; and anyway the syntax ends up being pretty horrible.
3. I actually wouldn't discount just using sine waves directly, specifically the `FSinOsc` UGen, which uses a very efficient sine approximation, or `DynKlang`, which takes an Array reference.

   Here's an example with 1000 instances of `FSinOsc`, making a quiet rumbling noise; it is currently using 22% CPU on my i5 Macbook (and this includes arbitrarily panning each oscillator):

   ```
   s = Server.local;
   s.waitForBoot { 

   n = 1000;

   ~freq = Array.rand(n, 20.0, 60.0).midicps;
   ~amp = Array.rand(n, 1/n * 0.01, 1/n * 0.5);
   ~pan= Array.rand(n, -1.0, 1.0);

   ~sines = Array.fill(n, { arg i; 
       { Pan2.ar( FSinOsc.ar(~freq[i], 0, ~amp[i]), ~pan[i]) }.play;
   });

   };
   ```

Of course option 1 is much, much more efficient - looks like by about a factor of 10. But you can't beat option 3 for simplicity.

Comment: a great answer!

Comment: thanks Dan! hm, maybe you know the answer to this: I am kind of assuming that the number of positive frequency bins is 1/2 of the FFT buffer size, or maybe 1/2 plus one... without digging into the source code... is that right?

Comment: Thank you for the great answer, Ezra!

I will try to play with 1. since I am restricted by Raspberry Pi.

Comment: then i guess i should note that this example probably doesn't affect the Nyquist bin :)